# Extract certain rows of data within a range

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA, I would like to extract certain rows of data within an invoice that are in a range of S0000000 to S9999999, the problem I am having is that all the data is in column A (after being converted from PDF) and is either tab and/or space delimited, its really messy. I wondering if there was some way I could put these rows into a new worksheet?

example

```
SS13 1TL        
T       
Y       PRICE          TRADE        
P                             DISC %        
VALUE            VAT  SOU       
Terms of Delivery  DAP      
8P1262*  S1311018           816 9781447211259    01 BK GB PM  Necessary Lies PB         Chamberlai P    0.80  0.00     651.98 1
8H3245*  S1311018           300 9780330538633    01 BK GB PM  Ruthless                  KEANE, Jes P    0.80  0.00     239.70 1
7J1782*  S1311018           300 9781447209522    01 BK GB PM  The Keystone (B)          Dean, A.M. P    0.80  0.00     239.70 1
7B9182*  S1311018           204 9780230760493    01 BK GB PM  Marked                    Jackson, D P    1.30  0.00     265.00 1
COM-CODE LEGEND 
BK  =  Books        
49019900
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a **`Text To Columns`** in the existing Spreadsheet using the Excel Menu (not VBA). You can specify tab or space as delimiter and split the data into multiple columns.

Here's a walkthrough: [How to parse data using the Text To Columns command in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261).

Comment: Hi Shiva, sorry just realized looking at the example I put they all look like they are lined up, however further along they no longer line up. What I am after is to extract any rows that are within the range of S000000000 to S999999999 into an new spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. So is this data in 1 text file or inside excel? Also, you want to put this data in a new excel spreadsheet with each space delimited value in it's own column?